# CSS : target an "<a>" tag element

Tags: html, css, xml

Say you have this html syntax :

```
<a href="#myId" aria-controls="hotel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">My Hotel</a>
```

What would be the CSS to target this tag, if I want to select the "aria-expanded" value, and the "href" value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this selector

```
a[href="#myId"][aria-expanded="true"]
```

more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: This is literally the same solution as mine. The `[href="#myId"]` is doing the same thing as the `a` in the beginning... seems redundant.

Comment: I think the question was about using multiple attributes selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS to target the `a href` and `aria-expanded` value would consist of the following:

```css
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myId" aria-controls="hotel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">My Hotel</a>
```